# Как оптимизировать запрос в prisma к дочерней структуре?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, prisma

у меня на входе есть 'email' по которому я нахожу структуру User, по ее id я далее нахожу связанную с ней структуру BasicInfo. Есть ли способ сделать это в один запрос?

// структура базы данных

```
model User {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
 
  basicInfo BasicInfo?
}

model BasicInfo {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user       User      @relation(fields:[userId], references:[id]) 
  userId     String    @db.ObjectId @unique
}

async deleteUser(where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput): Promise<User> {
  const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where })

  const basicInfo = await this.prisma.basicInfo.findUnique({
    where: { userId: user.id },
  })
  
  // хотелось бы что-нибудь такое, но так не работает :(
  // const basicInfo = await this.prisma.basicInfo.findUnique({
  //  where: { user: { connect: { where }} },
  //})
```

}